# Quartz.Net en ASP.Net con Autofac

Tags: asp.net, .net, cron, quartz

me surgió tener que implementar un cron en una API de .NET y no estoy logrando que se triggereen los Jobs. Explico y muestro mi código:

Tengo mi module de autofac:

```
 protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // Registra tus trabajos y sus dependencias aquí

        builder.RegisterType<CierreDeLoteCron>().As<IJob>(); 
        builder.RegisterType<JobService>().As<IJobService>();
        builder.RegisterType<CustomJobFactory>().As<IJobFactory>();
        builder.RegisterType<StdSchedulerFactory>().As<ISchedulerFactory>().SingleInstance();

        builder.Register(ctx =>
        {
            var schedulerFactory = ctx.Resolve<ISchedulerFactory>();
            return schedulerFactory.GetScheduler().Result;
        }).As<IScheduler>().SingleInstance();

        base.Load(builder);
    }
```

Luego tengo un HostedService que se encarga de cargar los triggers, porque requiero traerlos de un servicio a los horarios en los que deben correr los Jobs:

```
 public class NewScheduleQuartz : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IScheduler _scheduler;
    private readonly IJobService _jobScheduleService;
    public NewScheduleQuartz(IJobService jobService, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        _jobScheduleService = jobService;
        _scheduler = scheduler;
    }       
    public string ConvertDateTimeToCronExpression(TimeOnly time)
    {
        return $"{time.Second} {time.Minute} {time.Hour} ? * *";
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var jobSchedules = await _jobScheduleService.GetJobSchedules();

        foreach (var jobSchedule in jobSchedules)
        {
            var jobType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(jobSchedule.JobName);
            if (jobType == null || !typeof(IJob).IsAssignableFrom(jobType))
            {
                // Manejar el error: el tipo de trabajo no es válido
                continue;
            }

            var jobKey = new JobKey(jobSchedule.JobName);
            var jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create(jobType)
            .WithIdentity(jobKey)
            .Build();

            var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("myTrigger", "group1")
                .StartNow()
                .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(x => x
                    .OnEveryDay()
                    .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(jobSchedule.RunTime.Hour, jobSchedule.RunTime.Minute))
                    .WithIntervalInMinutes(1))
                .ForJob(jobKey)
                .Build();
            await _scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(true);
            await _scheduler.Start().ConfigureAwait(true);
        }




    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Por ultimo tengo el Job que estoy queriendo correr

```
public class CierreDeLoteCron:IJob
{
    private readonly ILoteService _loteService;
    public CierreDeLoteCron(ILoteService loteService)
    {
        _loteService = loteService;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        await CerrarLotes();
    }

    public async Task CerrarLotes()
    {
        await _loteService.CerrarLoteTerminales();
    }
}
```

Estuve debuggeando y veo que cuando crea el JOB y el TRIGGER lo hace correctamente, entiende bien cual es la clase de la debe hacer el JOB y el horario que establece el TRIGGER también es correcto.

Antes desde Program le daba Start y cuando paraba a hacer el ScheduleJob() estaba corriendo el _schedule. Después vi otros ejemplos donde le dan start después y cambié de lugar. También agregué el ".ConfigureAwait(true)" para ver si ese era el problema pero resulta que no.

También probé la librería https://github.com/alphacloud/Autofac.Extras.Quartz

cambiando la parte donde se registra el schedule por

```
cb.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacFactoryModule()); 
cb.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacJobsModule());
```

Y el comportamiento fue exactamente el mismo, parece que se configura todo perfecto pero nunca corre el JOB.

Ya vengo de varias horas renegando con esto y la info es bastante escasa, si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería muchísimo. Gracias desde ya. Saludos!